# Necesito graficar el error de una funcion ingresando como parametro un vector pero no soy capaz de lograrlo

Tags: array, matlab

Creo que solo debe ser un error conceptual de vectores pero es de mis primeros dias en matlab, agradeceria su ayuda!.

Como entrada estoy ingresando h = (linspace(1,10,10)*10.^-9) pero no logro graficar nada

```
function [ ] = problema1(h)   
real = cos(0.9); %solucion real de f'(x), x = 0.9
funA = (sin(h+0.9)-sin(0.9))/h;
funB = (sin(0.9+h)-sin(0.9-h))/(2*h);
errorA = abs(real-funA);
errorB = abs(real-funB);

%rutina inciso a;
if errorA < errorB
    disp("el error es menor en la ecuacion derivada hacia adelante");
else
    disp("el error es menor en la ecuacion derivada centradamente");
end

%grafica inciso b y c:
plot(h,errorA);
hold on;
plot(h,errorB);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Matlab hay que tener cuidado con los operadores aritméticos cuando se realizan operaciones elemento a elemento con vectores. Entiendo que en el caso que describes, lo que requieres es aplicar las expresiones de error a cada valor de `h`; en esta situación el operador `/` que colocas realiza una operación distinta a la que esperarías y te devuelve un escalar. La solución es utilizar el operador de división elemento a elemento `./`, que como notarás, es simplemente adicionar un punto antecediendo a la diagonal. Es decir, tu código pasaría a ser algo como:

```
function [ ] = problema1(h)   
real = cos(0.9); %solucion real de f'(x), x = 0.9
funA = (sin(h+0.9)-sin(0.9))./h;
funB = (sin(0.9+h)-sin(0.9-h))./(2*h);
errorA = abs(real-funA);
errorB = abs(real-funB);

%rutina inciso a;
if errorA < errorB
    disp("el error es menor en la ecuacion derivada hacia adelante");
else
    disp("el error es menor en la ecuacion derivada centradamente");
end

%grafica inciso b y c:
plot(h,errorA);
hold on;
plot(h,errorB);
```

Con esto deberías tener una gráfica de salida. Puedes revisar más información sobre operadores aritméticos en https://la.mathworks.com/help/matlab/arithmetic.html?lang=en